# Option for ElasticSearch Nest if you are still on .net Framework 4

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to use ElasticSearch Nest but my application is using .net Framework 4. What other options do I have? 
I have tried PlainElastic.net but it has not been updated lately.
If there is no other option, what I am thinking to try is generate the query.

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you make a case to update from .NET Framework 4? It's over 10 years old  and unsupported by Microsoft since 2016, so no security patches or fixes.

Comment: I wish I could  upgrade but hands are tied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a simple class to build the query. It works for my scenario, hope it can help someone else:

```
public class SearchQuery
{
    public int size { get; set; }
    public int from { get; set; }
    public Query query { get; set; }

    public SearchQuery()
    {
        size = 50;
        from = 0;
        query = new Query();
    }


}

public class Query
{
    public boolquery @bool { get; set; }

    public Query()
    {
        @bool = new boolquery();
    }


}

public class boolquery
{
    public JArray must { get; set; }
    public JArray should { get; set; }
    public boolquery()
    {
        must = new JArray();
        should = new JArray();
    }
}

public static class QueryCommands
{
    public static dynamic AddMatch(string field, dynamic value)
    {
        dynamic m = new JObject();
        m.match = new JObject(new JProperty(field, value));
        return m;
    }

    public static dynamic AddTerm(string field, dynamic value)
    {
        dynamic m = new JObject();
        m.term = new JObject(new JProperty(field, value));
        return m;
    }
    public static dynamic AddMatchPhrase(string field, dynamic value)
    {
        dynamic m = new JObject();
        m.match_phrase = new JObject(new JProperty(field, value));
        return m;
    }
}
```